# javascript do while, not writing last loop

Tags: javascript, do-while

I'm working on some homework, and this last problem is kicking my rear, every time I run it, it doesn't display the last loop of information entered.  So entering 3 loops, only 2 will show.

Thanks for any and all help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Casino_Eric</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.write( "<h1>Casino_Eric</h1>" );
        var CashierID, CustomerCount=0, TotalChips, OverAllValue, EndOrContinue;
        var BlueValue = 5, BlackValue = 20, RedValue = 50, GreenValue = 100;
        var BlueQty, BlackQty, RedQty, GreenQty;
        var BlueResult, BlackResult, RedResult, GreenResult;

        CashierID = window.prompt("Enter 6 digit cashier ID.", "000000");
            do{
                BlueQty = window.prompt("Enter Number of Blue Chips", "0");
                BlackQty = window.prompt("Enter Number of Black Chips", "0");
                RedQty = window.prompt("Enter Number of Red Chips", "0");
                GreenQty = window.prompt("Enter Number of Green Chips", "0");

                BlueResult = BlueQty * BlueValue;
                BlackResult = BlackQty * BlackValue;
                RedResult = RedQty * RedValue;
                GreenResult = GreenQty * GreenValue;
                OverAllValue = BlueResult + BlackResult + RedResult + GreenResult;


                EndOrContinue = parseInt(window.prompt("Would you like to end your shift now "+CashierID+" or count the chips for another customer?  Enter 1 to contiue, or N to quit.", "n"));
                    if(isNaN(EndOrContinue));
                    else{
                    CustomerCount++;
                    document.write("<p>Cashier ID: "+CashierID+", Customer : "+CustomerCount+"</br> Number of Blue Chips: "+BlueQty+", total value of Blue Chips is: "+BlueValue+"</br>Number of Black Chips: "+BlackQty+", total value of Black Chips is: "+BlackValue+"</br>Number of Red Chips: "+RedQty+", total value of Red Chips is: "+RedValue+"</br>Number of Green Chips: "+GreenQty+", total value of Green Chips is: "+GreenValue+"</br>This customer's total value is "+OverAllValue+".</p>");

                    }
                }
            while(!isNaN(EndOrContinue));


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <p>Reload for another conversion</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this line `if(isNaN(EndOrContinue));` at the bottom looks wrong to me, especially when followed by an `else`

Comment: this part: `if(isNaN(EndOrContinue));`  is really weird and should be revised.

Comment: @MildlyInteresting, yeah, it should just be `if (!isNaN....) { do the things....`, rather than ignoring the positive check and using the else for the logical inversion

Comment: In other news, does anyone actually see a reason why the loop in the above program should execute three times? Or any set number of times bar what the user actually enters?

Comment: Since this is "homework" consider that you end your shift prior to posting the last (however many) chip count to your page.  Arrest the cashier, he stole the last customers money!  So you check for your shift end at the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

It was due to the misplacement of if statement. Now it will work fine for you

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Casino_Eric</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            document.write( "<h1>Casino_Eric</h1>" );
            var CashierID, CustomerCount=0, TotalChips, OverAllValue, EndOrContinue;
            var BlueValue = 5, BlackValue = 20, RedValue = 50, GreenValue = 100;
            var BlueQty, BlackQty, RedQty, GreenQty;
            var BlueResult, BlackResult, RedResult, GreenResult;

            CashierID = window.prompt("Enter 6 digit cashier ID.", "000000");
                do{
                    BlueQty = window.prompt("Enter Number of Blue Chips", "0");
                    BlackQty = window.prompt("Enter Number of Black Chips", "0");
                    RedQty = window.prompt("Enter Number of Red Chips", "0");
                    GreenQty = window.prompt("Enter Number of Green Chips", "0");

                    BlueResult = BlueQty * BlueValue;
                    BlackResult = BlackQty * BlackValue;
                    RedResult = RedQty * RedValue;
                    GreenResult = GreenQty * GreenValue;
                    OverAllValue = BlueResult + BlackResult + RedResult + GreenResult;

                        document.write("<p>Cashier ID: "+CashierID+", Customer : "+CustomerCount+"</br> Number of Blue Chips: "+BlueQty+", total value of Blue Chips is: "+BlueValue+"</br>Number of Black Chips: "+BlackQty+", total value of Black Chips is: "+BlackValue+"</br>Number of Red Chips: "+RedQty+", total value of Red Chips is: "+RedValue+"</br>Number of Green Chips: "+GreenQty+", total value of Green Chips is: "+GreenValue+"</br>This customer's total value is "+OverAllValue+".</p>");


                    EndOrContinue = parseInt(window.prompt("Would you like to end your shift now "+CashierID+" or count the chips for another customer?  Enter 1 to contiue, or N to quit.", "n"));
                        if(!isNaN(EndOrContinue)){
                        CustomerCount++;
                        }
                    }while(!isNaN(EndOrContinue));


            </script>
        </head>
        <body>  
            <p>Reload for another conversion</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

as a "homework" example/question (thanks for your honesty) my answer is in that vein of thought - you have to do your own work but this should help:

```
 EndOrContinue = parseInt(window.prompt("Would you like to end your shift now "+CashierID+" or count the chips for another customer?  Enter 1 to contiue, or N to quit.", "n"));
                    if(isNaN(EndOrContinue));
                    else{
                    CustomerCount++;
                    document.write("<p>Cashier ID: "+CashierID+", Customer : "+CustomerCount+"</br> Number of Blue Chips: "+BlueQty+", total value of Blue Chips is: "+BlueValue+"</br>Number of Black Chips: "+BlackQty+", total value of Black Chips is: "+BlackValue+"</br>Number of Red Chips: "+RedQty+", total value of Red Chips is: "+RedValue+"</br>Number of Green Chips: "+GreenQty+", total value of Green Chips is: "+GreenValue+"</br>This customer's total value is "+OverAllValue+".</p>");

                    }
                }
            while(!isNaN(EndOrContinue));
```

Here  you set the value based on a question - ok there.

- Then you check that value set from the question **before** you do anything with the previous entries
- Then you forget (skip) to do what you need to do with those previous entries
- Then you check the question response (again)

Why do you even check the first time (inside your loop)?  Can you remove that?